# How do you refactor nested callbacks and pass parameters to each function in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to refactor some javascript code in Node, and I am having some trouble passing parameters to functions that are callbacks for other functions.  For example this is my set of callbacks:

```
userSchema.pre("save",function(next){
    var user = this;
    if (!user.isModified(value)) {return next();}
    bcrypt.genSalt(10,function(err,salt){
        if (err) {return next(err);}
        bcrypt.hash(user.password,salt,function(err,hash){
            if (err) {return next(err);}
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});
```

I want to refactor the callbacks to something like this so it looks cleaner and do so without an external library like async or q

```
userSchema.pre("save",function(next){
    var user = this;
    if (!user.isModified(value)) {return next();}
    bcrypt.genSalt(10,saltCallback(user));
});
function saltCallback(user){
    return function(err,salt){
        bcrypt.hash(user,salt,hashCallback(user));
    }
}
function hashCallback(user){
    return function(err,hash){
        if (err) {return next(err);}
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    }
}
```

The problem with what I'm trying to do is that I can't seem to find a way to pass dependent parameters between functions to get this refactoring to work.

If anyone could give me some pointers on this that'd be great

Comment: You need to pass both, user and next.

Comment: Or you define the two functions saltCallback and hashCallback inside your first function.

Comment: @SpiderPig passing both user and next doesn't work, in that specific code example it leads to an unhashed password

Comment: That may be because you wrote `bcrypt.hash(user,salt,hashCallback(user));` instead of `bcrypt.hash(user.password,salt,hashCallback(user));`

Comment: @SpiderPig Ok awesome I figure it out thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different ways of doing this. Either pass both, user and next.

```
userSchema.pre("save",function(next){
    var user = this;
    if (!user.isModified(value)) {return next();}
    bcrypt.genSalt(10,saltCallback(user, next));
});
function saltCallback(user, next){
    return function(err,salt){
        bcrypt.hash(user.password,salt,hashCallback(user, next));
    }
}
function hashCallback(user, next){
    return function(err,hash){
        if (err) {return next(err);}
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    }
}
```

Or define the two functions inside the first function.

```
userSchema.pre("save",function(next){
    function saltCallback(err,salt){
        bcrypt.hash(user.password,salt,hashCallback);
    }
    function hashCallback(err,hash){
        if (err) {return next(err);}
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    }
    var user = this;
    if (!user.isModified(value)) {return next();}
    bcrypt.genSalt(10,saltCallback);
});
```